# Label word wrap in PyQt5 doesn't take up space with stretch

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I have an application where I want a custom widget to not resize any larger than its content (i.e. even if app is fullscreen, don't stretch out buttons, labels, etc.). I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62657281/how-do-i-stop-a-custom-widget-from-expanding-in-pyqt5/62664956#62664956) about how to make this happen, however there is an issue: if I set a QLabel to word wrap, it doesn't take up as much space as it could. I still want to take up the minimum space possible but only word wrapping at the edge of screen space (i.e. taking up horizontal space is preferred over vertical space). Is there any way of doing this in PyQt5? There is example code below, and my actual code for which I want to implement this is at https://github.com/Jachdich/blechat-changeme if it is of any use.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class CustomWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout  = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button A")
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button B")
        self.label1  = QtWidgets.QLabel("Long label that can span multiple columns this is actually a long message tbh and it needs word wrap really.")
        self.label1.setWordWrap(True)
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label1, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(2, 1)


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cw = CustomWidget()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cw)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
win = App()
status = app.exec_()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want the two buttons to stay the size they are and the label to extend horizontally when the window is resized. One way to achieve this with minimal modifications to the current code code is to extend the label into the third, expanding, column by using `self.layout.addWidget(self.label1, 1, 0, 1, 3)` instead of `self.layout.addWidget(self.label1, 1, 0, 1, 2)`.

[image: screen shot]